# Multiple attributes - is it possible to do variation by shape?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, fields-attributes

I am making a map of winter coat color for several species. I have two fields: species name and winter coat color. The latter can be either white or brown, and I would like to code, say, brown winter coat with circles and white winter coat with diamond, and then use colors to code species names. But Arcmap provides only two options: variation by color ramp and variation by size (see the picture).

Is there any way to do variation by shape in ArcMap?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me what field is affecting the 0-2 or 3-4 symbol sizes.  Is that a count or another field set up by the Symbol Size button?  Is it an integer field?  Are you actually wanting to use an Area field instead?  Points have no area, so what shape do you mean?  Probably you need to show how you set up the Symbol Size option and give a little more detail about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Multiple Attributes section under the Symbology tab in Layer Properties. Set your fields to Species Name and Winter Coat Color, adjust your symbols accordingly.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. In this section, I can change colors and symbol sizes, but not shapes :(

Comment: Yup. Exactly how you've done but change the symbols manually under the list of values you have in the image. Left click on one value then shift or CTRL click to multi-select then select Properties for Selected Symbols'. Select a diamond or circle for which ever you selected for all selected values. Else, do individual combinations manually by double clicking on the symbol.

Comment: If you click on the shape symbol, you can change to whichever you'd like. Shape/Size etc.